# Where to initialize data for a view base class in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new base class for my MVC views, and created a property that must be poppulated from DB. This property is usefull for all my views, but I don't want the base view class to connect to the database, because I don't think this is correct. Where is the right place to initialize the view´s data?

Comment: If is it a static class, you could add it to App_Start folder and initialize at Application Start on Global.asax.

Comment: @Kaf It is not static, it is information about the logged user... like user preferences, personal information, and some other things that affects all views.

Comment: Then you could initialize and populate it just after a successful user login.

Comment: @Kaf's last comment seems logic to me and could be the answer.

Comment: is your data in static format or you are populating the views for each request?

Comment: When the user changes the preferences, or other configurations, then I have to show the changes in the view accordingly. So it is static as long as the user does not change his/her preferences and other configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single property why not just define it as TempData in your application? TempData will persist as you move from controller to controller unlike ViewBag or ViewData. Instead set the value of the TempData in your base class only if the TempData value does not exist. If it does then don't call the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Base Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177487/base-controller-class) which will be inherited by all other controllers. In the base controller, you get the profile data of user and populate a Session Variable or store it in [Cache object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then use the session or cache variables (through ViewBag properties in base controller) in your views. In case your session or cache expires, then base controller will do null checks and re-populate them again.